# Turing Decidability definition

Tags: computer-science

A language is Turing-decidable if there exists a Turing machine that always accepts strings in the language, rejects strings that are not in the language, but never loops.

Why is this statement false?
"never loops" should be "neven infinitely loops"?

Comment: "Loops" *means* "infinitely loops." (Actually, "doesn't halt" is better than "(infinitely) loops" in my opinion, but this is a minor point.)

Comment: Which clause would you remove to make it true?